# Is there a way to change Y-Axis values using a drop down in Telerik RadHTMLChart?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to change the type of data in the Y-Axis in my line graph based on drop down selection. For example I have a drop down that has population of dogs and cats as options for the Y-Axis values. I know I have to change the **DataFieldY** in the chart somehow but I am not able to do so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          var newDataSource = [
          {
              "Cats": "Cats",
              "Dogs": "Dogs",
              "Dog Population": "30",
              "Cat Population": 20,
              "Year": 2015,
          },
          {
              "Cats": "Cats",
              "Dogs": "Dogs",
              "Dog Population": "28",
              "Cat Population": 22,
              "Year": 2016,
          }]
          var RadHtmlChart1 = $find('<%=RadHtmlChart3.ClientID %>');
          RadHtmlChart1.set_dataSource(newDataSource);
          RadHtmlChart1.set_transitions(true);
          RadHtmlChart1.repaint();

          });
      });
      function OnClientClicked1() {

      }
  </script> 

<div class="span4" id="lineChart">
            <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="RadHtmlChart3" Transitions="false" Width="700" Height="420"> 
            <PlotArea>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="Dog Population">
                        <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="Blue" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance MarkersType="Square" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                </Series>
                <XAxis AxisCrossingValue="0" Color="Black" MajorTickType="Outside" MinorTickType="Outside"
                    Reversed="false" MinValue="0" MaxValue="90" Step="10" DataLabelsField="Year">
                    <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="Year" RotationAngle="0" />
                    <MajorGridLines Color="#EFEFEF" Width="1" />
                    <MinorGridLines Color="#F7F7F7" Width="1" />
                    <TitleAppearance Position="Center" RotationAngle="0" Text="Year" />
                </XAxis>
                <YAxis AxisCrossingValue="0" Color="Black" MajorTickType="Outside"
                    Reversed="false" MinValue="0" Step="5">
                    <MajorGridLines Color="#EFEFEF" Width="1" />
                    <MinorGridLines Color="#F7F7F7" Width="1" />
                    <TitleAppearance Position="Center" RotationAngle="0" Text="Population"/>
                </YAxis>
            </PlotArea>
            </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
        </div>
```